# Camera face detection coords to screen coords

Tags: android, android-camera, coordinates

i've recently started playing with Android's camera api. And i'm using face detection and it's callback `setFaceDetectionListener`. I'm having trouble trying to understand how to convert the `faces[0].rect.centerX();` and `faces[0].rect.centerY()` to something i can use on screen like move a image around the face centered on that point.

can anyone help me understand how to convert from the coord system given by the camera to something i can use to set elements on my activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html)

> (-1000, -1000) represents the top-left of the camera field of view, and (1000, 1000) represents the bottom-right of the field of view.

So to put in to screen coords (pseudocode):

```
screenX = (coord.x +1000) * screen.width / 2000
screenY = (coord.y +1000) * screen.height / 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (assuming you have a width and a height integer variable):

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(faces[0].rect.centerX()-width/2,faces[0].rect.centerY()-height/2, 0,0);
```

...and to get the width and height:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    width=image.getWidth();
    height=image.getHeight();
}
```